# Install Windows 10 in UEFI mode without pen drive

Tags: windows-10, usb, uefi

Current Installed OS: Windows 7 x64 In UEFI mode

Motherboard: Asus H81M-CS In UEFI Mode

Wanted: To Install Windows 10 Pro x64 Version In UEFI Mode

Problem is: The ISO is of 3.80 GB and my pen drive is of 3.77 GB only!
So I cannot install make pen drive bootable through Rufus

So is there any way to install windows 10 UEFI from ISO without pen drive - through a partition of my HDD? or any work-around?

Comment: why not considering using a DVD, burn the iso and boot from DVD ?

Comment: Use a USB DVD drive, then create a installation DVD, and use that to install Windows.  Your only other solution, would be to use a different usb mass storage device, specifically a larger one.

Comment: @Neil because i do not have a DVD

Comment: @AwesomeIronman - Then there isn't a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Ramhound : it's not a tablet, it's a desktop.

Comment: @Ramhound please explain! I didnt understood

Comment: @AwesomeIronman - The only solution to your problem is to purchase a USB mass storage device, that has a larger capacity.

Comment: It’s certainly possible to have the Windows Setup boot from your hard disk. However, I’m not sure whether the Windows 7 Boot Manager can boot Windows 10 Setup.

Comment: guys aren't there methods to boot through ISO? on my older PC, which had BIOS I had did something like installing OS directly through ISO with easyBCD

Comment: @AwesomeIronman - You do not have the means to boot from the iSO since you don't have a DVD Drive nor do you have a USB mass storage device larger enough to contain it.  You should spend the $10 and get a larger mass storage device, or burrow one, from somebody

Comment: If you load the ISO on your hard drive, then mount it and run `setup.exe` on its root, you should be able to install the upgrade. I've done this. Although pen-drives are so cheap that I don't see why you don't buy a larger one. How do you back up? You'll need to do this before any attempt at installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it’s really easy, at least with a proper UEFI firmware:

1. Create temporary partition near the end of your disk
2. Format it with FAT32 (important!)
3. Copy over files from Windows ISO
4. Reboot and bring up the boot selection menu
5. Select the appropriate entry that does not read “Windows Boot Manager”

If you don’t get the required boot entry, or all you can get to boot is Windows 7, try with [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) on your USB drive. You can put the image (“A USB flash drive image file”) on your USB drive using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) or any other image writer.

In rEFInd, the boot entry will look like this:

[image]